# Determine the order of text/glyphs are highlighted in a PDF

Tags: ios, pdf

I have an .xlsx table I convert to a PDF. However when selecting (highlighting) the text/glyph in the pdf rather than select (highlight) the content in order it would in excel (left to right - top to bottom), it will highlight a few rows then a whole column then jump back up to highlight the other missed rows.

I know PDF isn’t a text file but is there anyway I can format a pdf so that the order in which text/glyphs are selected (highlighted) as user drags mouse/ finger over?

Comment: Highlight order is not generally specified and, therefore, is implementation dependant. Thus, there is no sure way to guarantee a given order. Nonetheless, if one draws and tags the text in reading order, one often gets what one wants.

Comment: @mkl thank you sounds like I need adobe acrobat pro. Unless you can recommend another Mac software to select reading order